# Terminating a threadpool

Tags: c, pthreads, signals, ipc

I'm trying to create a program that receives messages from various applications through a common queue (as it stands, a POSIX message queue) and dispatches these commands to a pool of worker threads.

I've changed designs more than I can remember over the last days, so rather than badly reinventing the wheel, I thought I'd come here for advice, specifically regarding how to terminate the program.

I'd like the termination event to be received through the queue, and acknowledged by a worker (so that the dispatcher does not bother pre-processing the command, which may imply authentication-checking to be done by a worker).

Thus I need a way for the information to somehow come back from a worker up to the dispatcher, to tell the latter to stop.

In my current iteration, the main thread is the dispatcher thread, receiving from the queue and exchanging signals (through conditional variables) with workers to inform idle threads of pending commands. The way I see it, signals will have to enter the picture:

- if the queue is non-blocking, the dispatcher will call (in order) `mq_notify`, `mq_receive` and `sigwait` after receiving `EAGAIN` ;
- if the queue is blocking, the dispatcher will simply call `mq_receive`, which will return with `EINTR` when interrupted by a signal.

In both cases the dispatcher will be running `while(atomic_load(state) != POOL_TERMINATING)`, which will be set by the worker that authenticates the terminating command and raises a signal.

Now for the questions:

1. Is there anything I need worry about when using signals and threads, beside that it's not a trivial exercise? ([sample](http://devcry.heiho.net/html/2009/20090524-pthreads-unix-signals.html))
2. Is there any reason I should bother with a non-blocking queue for the dispatcher, since its only job is to forward messages?

   - If there is, can someone cure me from my paranoid fear that a "new message" notification is going to arrive between `if (ret == EAGAIN)` and `sigwait()`?
3. If I go for the blocking queue, can I do without a handler? I.e. the worker sets `POOL_TERMINATING`, sends the signal, and `mq_receive` simply returns with `EINTR` if the dispatcher was receiving (I don't know enough about signals yet to see a way to tell the system "interrupt a call such as `mq_receive`, but don't bother with handlers", so I guess it will be an empty handler).
4. Am I DoingItWrong™?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1+ for thinking about end in the beginning ...!-)

Comment: If using non-blocking queues, I do not see the need to use signals.

Comment: Ideally, I would like the dispatcher to broadcast a "new event" signal when it knows it's time to terminate, so that workers stop waiting and return (seeing the state is "TERMINATING" rather than "NEW_MESSAGE").

With a non-blocking queue, `mq_notify` can either spawn a new thread or send a signal to inform of a new message. I guess if I used a thread, I could have my dispatcher wait on another conditional variable, which would be signaled by the newly spawned thread OR by the worker detecting termination? Thank you for questioning my assumptions :)

Comment: Do **not** use signals for synchronisation, use conditions and mutexes and/or semaphores. Sending signals is **only** necessary to interrupt blocking system calls. So to keep things simple(r) **avoid** blocking system calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credits for this go to alk, who made me think twice about the "necessity" of
using signals (well, signals as in `signal(7)`, since I did use
`pthread_cond_signal(3)`). In the end, I even managed to use a non-blocking
queue, without any fear of missing a new-message notification.

Some pseudo-code: (the final code is functional, but it's... not exactly suited
for educational purposes).

```
DISPATCHER:

  mq_open();
  mq_notify(dispatcher_callback);

  while (state != TERMINATING)

    switch (state) 

      case WAITING:

        while (dispatcher_event == NO_EVENT)
          wait(dispatcher_event);

        state = (dispatcher_event == NEW_MSG) ? RECEIVING :
                (dispatcher_event == TERM)    ? TERMINATING : WAITING;

      case RECEIVING:

        if (mq_receive() > -1)
          signal(worker_event, NEW_MSG);
          forward_command();

        else if (errno == EAGAIN)
          state = WAITING;
          dispatcher_event = NO_EVENT;

  worker_event = TERM;
  broadcast(worker_event, TERM);

  for (w ∈ workers)
    pthread_join(w.id);

  return;


WORKER:

  while (state != TERMINATING)

    switch (state)

      case IDLE:

        while (worker_event == NO_EVENT)
          wait(worker_event);

        state = (worker_event == NEW_MSG) ? BUSY :
                (worker_event == TERM)    ? TERMINATING : IDLE;

      case BUSY:

        worker_event = NO_EVENT;
        worker_fetch_command();
        worker_process_command();
        state = IDLE;

  return;
```

An "event" object is composed of a conditional variable, a mutex and an
enumerated type (hence the `signal()`/`broadcast()`/`wait()` calls, mixed with
assignments and comparisons). The `while (!predicate_change) wait(predicate);`
idiom is meant to handle spurious wake-ups.

The dispatcher and worker threads share a common "pool" object which contains
two events (one for the dispatcher, one for the whole worker pool), and a buffer
where the command is picked up.

Not pictured:

- Appropriate `lock()`/`unlock()` calls before and after
  reading/writing/signaling/waiting on those "events".
- Some more synchronization between `dispatcher_forward()` and
  `worker_fetch_command()`.
- Those "state" variables are thread-local.
- `dispatcher_callback()` calls `mq_notify()` again, then signals `dispatcher_event`, setting it to `NEW_MSG`.
- `process_command()` signals `dispatcher_event` when it recognizes and
  authenticates the "TERMINATE" command.
- Error checking.
- ... A few `printf()` calls.

**EDIT:** after thinking about it some more, I figured I could do without a dispatcher thread entirely:

- the workers can call `mq_receive()` without blocking;
- the notification callback can signal/broadcast an event directly to the pool;
- the worker identifying a termination command can also broadcast the event to the pool, rather than bouncing back to the dispatcher.

Comment: So this is using a `SIGEV_THREAD` notification function for the `mq_notify()` -- so that it can grab the required mutex and update the dispatcher state, yes ?

Comment: Yep. After sleeping on it and thinking about your point about workers calling `mq_receive()` directly, I realized I could indeed do without a dispatcher thread and have the notification handler signal/broadcast an event directly to the workers. The main thread would just create the pool and join whenever he feels like it; at some point a thread will identify a termination command and broadcast the event directly to all workers.

Answer (score 1):

The signal you are waiting on in `sigwait()` must be blocked (masked) outside the `sigwait()` in order to ensure that it is not delivered at any other time.

Given that your dispatch loop is waiting on the incoming messages, it is tempting to simply block in `mq_receive()`.  HOWEVER, I don't see how you avoid a signal race when the worker thread that sees the "end" message signals that fact.  You could, perhaps, `mq_send()` a special "STOP" message to the dispatch loop -- perhaps by setting the `POOL_TERMINATING` flag and sending an empty message ?

You mention signalling with condition variables to dispatch the messages to the worker threads.  That implies you have some internal queue, protected by the condition's mutex.  If this is the case, then you could put your `POOL_TERMINATING` flag under the mutex as well, and use a `pthread_cond_broadcast()` to wake up all the threads.

If you let the worker threads do `mq_receive()` for themselves -- which looks plausible enough -- then you have a small problem delivering a signal to all of them to terminate.  The main thread would, in this case, wait to be told that the termination message has been received.  Before collecting the workers (I assume) by pthread_join() you would need to `pthread_kill()` each one, in case it was blocked in `mq_receive()`.  HOWEVER, it's not clear to me how you avoid a signal race... and this starts to look very nasty.  This could be one of the (few IMHO) times when `pthread_cancel()` is useful... you could set the workers `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE` and `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED`, and set `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE` just before `mq_receive()`.  Or... similar to the above, you could `mq_send()` "STOP" messages for all the workers.

In passing, I think what is needed is a `pthread_prod()`, which is a cross between `pthread_kill()` and `pthread_cancel()`... a sort of a signal, masked except at (during) cancellation points.  This would generalise the sort of thing that `pselect()` does with its magic "atomic" shuffling of signal masks.

Comment: *Interrupting the dispatcher*: the solution I had in mind, at the time, was to
have the dispatcher thread catch a process signal which would make
`mq_receive()` return with `EINTR`.

*Resorting to `pthread_kill()`/`cancel()`*: I ended up with a solution which
involves neither, cf. my answer.

Comment: Re "signal race when the worker thread that sees the "end" message signals that fact".  I assume you're refering a race where a signal is intended to stop a blocking operation but in fact is received immediately before starting the blocking operation?

One way of avoid that is to siglongjump() out of the signal handler rather than normal return.

I prefer the use-a-message-not-a-signal solution.

Comment: @user1998586: yes, that's exactly it.  If a blocking mq_receive() were to be used, then using a signal to tell the dispatcher that the "end" message has been received is in danger of sending that signal before the dispatcher gets round to the mq_receive.  This is the same problem that pselect() is designed to avoid.   I have to say that I feel that anyone contemplating a siglongjump() is in a state of sin :-)